# How many indexes can I create in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am very new to elastic search and its applications, I found that elastic search saves data(indexes) onto disk. Then I wondered: Are there any limitations on number of indexes that can be created or can I create as many as I can since I have a very large disk space?

Currently I have elastic search deployed using a single node cluster with Docker. I have read something about shards and its limitation etc., but I was not able to understand it properly.

Is there anyone on SO, who can shed some light onto these questions for a newbie in layman terms?

What is a single node cluster and how does my data get saved onto disk? Also what are shards and how is it related to elastic search?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best answer is "it depends ". Generally there is no limitation for having many indexes , Every index has its own mapping and irrelevant to other indexes by default, Actually indexes are instance of Elasticsearch servers and please note that they are not data rather you may think about as entire database alone. There are many variables for answering this question for example if are planning to have replication of your shards in one index then you may found limitation due to the size of document you are planning to ingest inside the index.

As an other note you may need to ask first why I need many indexes ? for enhancing search operation or queries throughput? if it is the case then perhaps its better to use replica shards beside your primary shards in the single index because the queries are executed parallel to each other in replica shards and you can think of shards as an stand alone index inside of your main index so in conclusion I can say there is no limitation as long as you have enough free space to save new data (expanding inverted indexes table created for on field) but regarding to you needs it may be better to have primary and replica shards inside an index .